# How to solve error on sending game action

Tags: python, telethon

Im trying to send gaming action but i got this error :

Connot cast event to any kind of peer

This is my code :

```
gaming = "on"
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
def handler(event):
    global gaming
    if gaming == "on":
        async with client.action("game",event):
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of [`client.action`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.action) is the chat ("entity") where you want to send the action, not the action itself. `"game"` is not a valid entity (nobody has this username):

```py
async with client.action(event.chat_id, "game"):
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
```